# Bluetooth stopped working after dual booting with windows BCM43142

Tags: linux, arch-linux, drivers, dual-boot, bluetooth

Bluetooth works well until dual boot with windows

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit     Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI 
Express Card Reader (rev     01)
```

I always get "No default controller available" as a message

```
>bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show 
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#

>>lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b42d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Front Camera
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai BCM43142A0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 275d:0a29  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0529:0001 Aladdin Knowledge Systems HASP copy protection dongle
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I found that by running 'rfkill block bluetooth' and 'rfkill unblock bluetooth' many times at random the device will work again (but stops working after restart)

```
>>rfkill list
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: nfc0: NFC
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
13: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

**What is working for me, but I have to do it every time I use Windows and then go back to Arch:**

(Just once)
added 'blacklist sony_laptop' to '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'

Routine after returning to the arch:

1-) `sudo modprobe sony_laptop` 

2-) `rfkill block bluetooth`

3-) `blueman-adapters`  click button "enable bluettoth"

If I don't boot windows I don't need to do this routine.

Comment: can you run `lsusb`

Comment: I found that by running 'rfkill block bluetooth' and 'rfkill unblock bluetooth' many times at random the device will work again

Comment: but stops working after restart